# Excel Charts for table with many duplicates

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table, duplicates, duplicate-data

I have a list of names with 1000 entries and maybe 750 unique.  There are other attributes, like location and position.  Can I create a pivot table that would show me simple stat's like X number of unique people, X number unique in location 1, location 2, location 3, and finally x number of positions in location 1, position 2/location1, position 3/location2...?

```
Name    Location    Title
Smith, Bob  UK  Sales Manager
Smith, Bob  UK  Plant Manger
Jones, Keith    UK  Sales Manager
Jones, Keith    UK  Plant Foreman
White, Derick   Denver  Sales Manager
Brown, Frank    Boston  Supply Chain
Black, Jay  Denver  Sales Manager
Smith, Jeff Denver  Sales Manager
Gonzalez, Al    UK  
Gonzalez, Al    UK  Staging Area Manager
Bright, Susan   Denver  Legel Secretary
Bright, Susan   Denver  Paralegal
Bright, Susan   Denver  Executive Assistant
Bright, Susan   Denver  Press Secretary
Alf, Jeff   Denver  VP, Sales
Green, Burt Boston  VP, Sales
Jones, Chuck    Denver  Plant Foreman
Alten, Cory Denver  Sales Manager
Clark, Jerry    Boston  Plant Foreman
Romo, Tom   Denver  Sales Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using CountifS functions in adjacent columns to the data. For example to count unique people, just create a column (call it column x for this example) and enter =Countif(Column A, A1) and copy down for all the rows. then just enter =countif(Column X, 1) and that should give you the unique names. 
You can use CountifS function for more complicated counting logic to answer the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar counting of unique entries using pivot tables.

I create a additional column that has a 1 if it is the first occurance of the "key" (ie name).  The formula is similar to this:  (assume Column A has the "key")

```
=IF(ROW(A1) = MATCH(A1,A:A,0),1,0)
```

This formula is then copied down for every row (or if it's a proper table, it's auto copied!)
The idea is that the MATCH returns the row number of the first occurrence of "key".  If it is the same as the current row, then count 1.  If the values aren't the same, it's a duplicate, so give it a 0 value.

When you then do a pivot table sum on this value, it adds up to the number of unique entries. (ie unique names in a region.)